# Background still remains after Bootstrap 4 modal disappears

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap 4 modal, when I click on "Ok" button I call function and after that the modal disappear, but the back-ground still remains. whereas for the close button the modal and the back-ground dissapers its because I am using "data-dismiss="modal", but if I use this same for "Ok" button this is not working. I have used (data-backdrop="false"), but it completely removes the back-ground which i donot want. so can someone please tell me how to do that. I have uploaded the following code.

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>{{question}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onConfirm($event)">Ok</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.ts File

```
export class ModalComponent  {
@Input() question: string = ''
@Input() title: string = ''
@Output() confirm = new EventEmitter<void>() 
constructor() { }
onConfirm(event: Event) {
event.stopPropagation()
this.confirm.emit()
}

}
```

Comment: You should upload a working minimal example. We can't know how you treat your modal if we don't see minimal reproducible example

Comment: Why do u need the event.stopPropagation in the function onConfirm() function?